# Have I correctly specified the lmer model?

Tags: r, self-study, lme4-nlme

a simple two-level model, with one explanatory
variable at the individual level (X) and one explanatory variable
at the group level (Z):

$$Y_{ij}=\gamma_{00}+\gamma_{10}X_{ij}+\gamma_{01}Z_{j}+\gamma_{11}X_{ij}Z_{j}+u_{0j}+u_{1j}X_{ij}+e_{ij}$$

covariance between $u_{0j}$ and $u_{1j}$ is $0$ . I have specified the `lmer` model as :

```
model <- lmer(Y~X+Z+X:Z+(X||group),data=dat)
```

Have I correctly specified the lmer model . Should it be `(X||group)` or `(X+Z||group)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

Because you only have one random slope, i.e., that for $X$, you do not need to add $Z$ into the random-effect model. So the correct specification is `(X||group)` for uncorrelated random effects.